# How can I use categorical/factor input for NeuralNet model with R

Tags: r

I have tried to perform artificial neural network(ann) with R and my data has some categorical/factor variables. As far as I know I need to create some dummy variables to handle this problem and I'll probably need to introduce the variables to model.

I have tried to use `model.matrix` method and created the ann model. However, I couldnt compute it with test data which has exactly the same format with training data except the sales column.

I know the problem occurs after I created dummy variables. The model cannot find the same column name and can't compute. How can I use my test data and compute the ann?

Here is my data str;

```
'data.frame':   142 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ category: Factor w/ 3 levels "WJP","WPI","WSLS": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ mm      : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ profile : Factor w/ 4 levels "K","L","M","X": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ nv      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ vp      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ color   : Factor w/ 17 levels "B","BEG","BL",..: 17 1 9 3 14 15 3 17 3 17 ...
 $ cli     : Factor w/ 2 levels "OTHER","SEASON": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ stylec  : int  3 3 3 3 6 3 6 3 3 3 ...
 $ rtn     : int  17 2 2 2 2 2 4 7 2 2 ...
 $ dev     : num  2.51 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
 $ stosale : num  10.75 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
 $ dm1     : num  19507.8 19.6 14.6 19.6 36.9 ...
 $ dm2     : num  3092.74 5 4.2 5 7.74 ...
 $ dm3     : num  1691.04 3.75 3.31 3.75 5.25 ...
 $ grossp  : num  2710.98 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
 $ grossDM : num  2.48 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
 $ firstsp : num  39.67 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
 $ qty     : num  106213 7661 6671 23500 18722 ...
 $ sales   : num  272.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
```

Here is the code:

```
library(neuralnet)
df<- read.csv("de2.csv",sep=";")

df_matrix <- model.matrix(~ category+ mm + profile + nv + vp + color + cli + stylec + rtn + dev + stosale + dm1 + dm2 + dm3 + grossp + grossDM + firstsp + qty + sales, data=df)
colnames(df_matrix)

col_list <- paste(c(colnames(df_matrix[,-c(1,39)])),collapse="+")
col_list <- paste(c("sales~",col_list),collapse="")
f <- formula(col_list)

set.seed(7896129)
nn1=neuralnet(f, data=df_matrix, hidden=3, act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = FALSE)

dft<- read.csv("deft.csv",sep=";")
result=compute(nn1, dft)
result$net.result
```

====================

I have found a solution for my problem but still would like to have an answer for my question. As a solution I have splitted my data as train and test data  and then run the neuralnet with train data by following codes. So instead of reading test data from another csv file as raw, I used same data. But still I would like to run my model for raw data if that is possible as in first place.

```
index <- sample(1:nrow(df_matrix),round(0.75*nrow(df_matrix)))
train <- df_matrix[index,]
test <- df_matrix[-index,]

nn1=neuralnet(f, data=train, hidden=3, act.fct = "logistic", linear.output =FALSE)
result=compute(nn1, test[,1:38])
```

Comment: It would help if you could clarifiy what you are referring to with "ann" and if you could use reproducible data.

Comment: I have used ann as artificial neural networks.

Comment: In this line `col_list <- paste(c(colnames(df_matrix[,-c(1,39)])),collapse="+")` you are removing columns 1 and 39, so you are removing “category” as well as “sales” from your formula, but I assume you still have “category” in your test data. Try it like this `col_list <- paste(c(colnames(df_matrix[,-c(39)])),collapse="+")`

Comment: If that doesn’t work and you need additional help I would recommend adding your data to your question using `dput()`, not `str()`

Comment: Actually I am not sure if that is problem. Because the `col_list` is just put in order my column names which modified by the `model.matrix` and it's outcome is something like this (with dummy variables of course) `sales~ category+ mm + profile + nv + vp + color + cli + stylec + rtn + dev + stosale + dm1 + dm2 + dm3 + grossp + grossDM + firstsp + qty` so I can use this as formula for neuralnet.  I checked my data with ´dput´ but it is so big for this.

Comment: I've just added my poor solution for the problem. But I am still looking for solution for the first situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have 142 observations and 19 variables.
One of your variables, 'color', has 17 levels.
When you split your data into train/test in the proportions 75/25 that means your test set would have 0.25*142 or about 35 observations. This would suggest that with a variable with 17 categories you may find that some or even many categories are missing in observations in the test.
Perhaps you need more data or less categories.
Can the 'color' categories be consolidated into a smaller number?
What happens when you drop 'color' from your model?

Can you get more data? If that is not possible you may be able to use 'jitter' methods to increase the size of your data.